# Regular expression to match no-extension file name string

Tags: regex, pcre

I've got some Postfix block-attachment based on file extension expression:

```
/^Content-(Disposition|Type).*name\s*=\s*"?(.*(\.|=2E)(
ade|adp|asp|bas|bat|chm|cmd|com|cpl|crt|dll|exe|
hlp|ht[at]|
inf|ins|isp|jse?|lnk|md[betw]|ms[cipt]|nws|
\{[[:xdigit:]]{8}(?:-[[:xdigit:]]{4}){3}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}\}|
ops|pcd|pif|prf|reg|sc[frt]|sh[bsm]|swf|
vb[esx]?|vxd|ws[cfh]))(\?=)?"?\s*(;|$)/x
```

as you can see, this matches `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=anythng.xyz`
where xyz may be numerous file extensions given above (bat, com, exe, sh...).

I was wandering how to include case when attached file is without extension?

Often there is binaries without extension, *nix OS's is the ones that count file without extension as possible binary.

So I would like in given expression to include option to match extensionless file name strings like: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=anythng`

How to have that? Thanks.

Comment: You can make any group in regex optional by appending `?`.

Comment: If you are trying to match "any executable", then you've missed a few for Windows. Why are you trying to do this, because this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Richard, well I'm trying to do best, this is better anything than nothing situation. Sure I'll miss some extensions.

Comment: You missed the main point of my comment: why do you want to identify executable downloads?

Comment: @Richard because it seems like no serious email provider allows (Gmail, Yahoo, Microsoft...) sending executables. Sometimes even when packed into .zip or .rar archive. I can't be better than them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this https://regex101.com/r/mI9qC6/1

```
^Content-(Disposition|Type).*name\s*=\s*"?([^.]*((\.|=2E)(
ade|adp|asp|bas|bat|chm|cmd|com|cpl|crt|dll|exe|
hlp|ht[at]|
inf|ins|isp|jse?|lnk|md[betw]|ms[cipt]|nws|
\{[[:xdigit:]]{8}(?:-[[:xdigit:]]{4}){3}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}\}|
ops|pcd|pif|prf|reg|sc[frt]|sh[bsm]|swf|
vb[esx]?|vxd|ws[cfh]))?)(\?=)?"?\s*(;|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

An extensionless file would be one without a period, so

```
…name\s*=\s*[^.]+$
```

would do it. But consider that this would not match `System.Controller` – where a period has been included as part of the name.